# Mac zsh terminal unable to connect to postgres servers

Tags: postgresql, macos, malloc, zsh

```
psql "host=backbone-dev.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname=postgres user=postgres@backbone-dev password=blabblahblah sslmode=require"
psql: error: connection to server at "backbone-dev.postgres.database.azure.com" (52.182.136.38), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format.
psql(1657,0x1fd7f5e00) malloc: double free for ptr 0x144008200
psql(1657,0x1fd7f5e00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
zsh: abort      psql
```

I have always been able to connect to postgres servers (provisioned by Azure) up until 2 days ago. Other people could connect to it, so it seems the **fault is within my laptop** but I do not know why.

Googled around the malloc error message but didn't find anything useful

I tried connecting using cloud shell on azure and that works too, once again affirming the error is within my laptop. But I do not know why or how to fix it.

Already contacted Azure support, and as always they don't know how to fix it.

Here is my psql version: psql (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Homebrew)

Comment: A binary which tries to free twice the same block of memoty, is not usually an indicator for a hardware fault. Since psql is causing the trouble, how about reinstalling it?

Comment: The first error seems to be from the server, but it must be an Azure add-on as that text is not present in community version of PostgreSQL.  But it hard to see how the same issue wouldn't arise with other users who try to use that same username.  The 2nd seems to be a bug in psql, or a misbehavior of the OS.  Maybe it is a bug in psql which is only hit when it tries to deal with non-standard errors from the server.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I'm able to connect with Postico but not psql. Postgres 14.9 from brew. It's baffling.

Comment: @voxobscuro in case you haven't figured it out. I had to reinstall psql, and it has worked.